# Need some help to regex match a JWT and a resource from URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently using a mix of javascript `slice()` and `substring()` methods to extract the jwt and resource path from a string that looks like this:

`?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YWJmYzhmYTE1Zjg4MzAwMWQxNDJiMzYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjI1MTgyNjY2NjV9.yl6iYkJ5_fLqWeDwQuBfZkxMSa7iCZrSP62_ypligNE&query=/resource&id=aa&cat=az`

I need to get the following variables:

1. **token** (should be `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YWJmYzhmYTE1Zjg4MzAwMWQxNDJiMzYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjI1MTgyNjY2NjV9.yl6iYkJ5_fLqWeDwQuBfZkxMSa7iCZrSP62_ypligNE`)
2. **query** (should be `/resource&id=aa&cat=az`)

I am convinced that this can easily done with regex to store the `token` and `query` variables but matching for jwt is proving to be quite difficult. Can someone explain to me the process?

Comment: The token and query are easy, what is the other thing you're having difficulty trying to match?

Comment: I'm guessing this is nodejs. Have you tried https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options ?

Comment: Wait, you want `query` to be `/resource&id=aa&cat=az`? Surely `id` and `cat` should be separate variables, if you even need them at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No regex needed

```js
const input = '?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YWJmYzhmYTE1Zjg4MzAwMWQxNDJiMzYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjI1MTgyNjY2NjV9.yl6iYkJ5_fLqWeDwQuBfZkxMSa7iCZrSP62_ypligNE&query=/resource&id=aa&cat=az';
const [token, query] = input.slice(7).split('&query=');
console.log([token, query])
```

Comment: This would set `token` to `token=...`. It would also set `query` to `/resource&id=aa&cat=az`, which probably isn't what OP wanted even though it's what he said.

Comment: Run the snippet, it looks to assign the proper values? `"eyJ0eXAiOiJK...`

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see the `slice` part. But I still think it's better to use `querystring`, and I still think the `query` part is wrong.

Comment: This is similar to what I did myself. Looks like using regex would be overengineering, so I am sticking with this answer.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the `token` is first and the `query` is second, and if you really did want `/resource&id=aa&cat=az` as a single thing, then I suppose this works. But it's not standard HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible with non greedy regex

```js
var largeString = "?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YWJmYzhmYTE1Zjg4MzAwMWQxNDJiMzYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjI1MTgyNjY2NjV9.yl6iYkJ5_fLqWeDwQuBfZkxMSa7iCZrSP62_ypligNE&query=/resource&id=aa&cat=az"

// from "token=" to the first &
var preToken = /token=(.*?)&/.exec(largeString);
var token = preToken[preToken.length - 1];

console.info(token);

// from "query=" to the last character
var preQuery = /query=(.*?)$/.exec(largeString);
var query = preQuery[preQuery.length - 1];

console.info(query);
```